# Copying HTML Input Element's Content to an ASP.NET TextBox from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have these both in my aspx file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbASP" runat="server" Width="400px" />
<input id="tbHTML">
```

How to copy the content of `tbHTML` to `tbASP` from code behind?

Comment: when you want to copy i mean on on submit of button

Comment: Yes and the code is in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Add runat="server" to input..

```
<input id="tbHTML" runat="server">
```

you will access in code behind..

2.Else use find control

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl tbHtml= this.FindControl("tbHtml") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl;
tbAsp.Text=tbHtml.value;
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Id of ur Input element is unique in page...than you can try like this.

```
tbASP.Text=Page.Request["tbHTML"].ToString();
```

**Edit Vice Versa**

```
  <input id="id" value=<%= TextBox1.Text %> />
```

Comment: Amit I hope you will still be able to see my reply. I just want to ask. From this approach that you provided how can I do this vise versa? I mean this time copying from asp textbox to html input element.

Comment: @ChrisN.P. glad to help u...happy coding